# Attach() or Listener for Events (such as onTweenComplete, onTweenUpdate)

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, flash-cs3, flashdevelop

I have an instance of an object that starts and stops tweens for sub-movieclips. However I want to do stuff when the tween is finished.

So I would like to assign a calling object to events; such as the `attach()` function does. However when using the `attach()` function on events it is called right away with the correct object, but when the event is triggered it is called with the object that executed the event (in my case the sub-movieclip).

If that's not possible; something similar to how Mouse events and MouseListeners work would also fit my needs `Mouse.addListener(this)`. By adding a listener for specific events to the current object, then when these events are called they are called on our own object.

I also saw some clever solutions that I do not really enjoy since they are not very nice:

```
var myObject = this;
myMovieClip.onTweenComplete = function() {
    myObject.doStuff();
}
```

Is there something nicer than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I'm not aware of an `attach()` function in Actionscript 2.

2) There are some useful tips [here](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/tween.htm) on how to use the `onMotionFinished` event.

3) Nice or not, you can use `onTweenComplete` by importing the [MCTween](http://hosted.zeh.com.br/mctween/doc_ontweencomplete.html) library.

Hope this helps.